# wordpress posts api shows blank page when called from external site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, php-curl

Ok so my work wants one of our websites to pull posts from another one of our wordpress website.

I found this endpoint and when I throw it in a browser or in post man I get the data no problem.

However when I do a basic curl request from my external website and echo the results it shows a blank page.  The request is a 200 ok but no data showing?

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array 
            (
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.hidden.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('title' => 'Sample Post','status' => 'publish'),
                ));
                
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);    
        echo $response;
```

I thought maybe I needed to be on https since this was on the local server but when pushed to secure dev server same issue.

Then I thought maybe I need to authenticate so I tried this:

```
$username='hiddenusr';
    $password='hiddenpass';
    $URL='https://www.hidden.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    echo $result;
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
    curl_close ($ch);
```

still nothing?  What am I doing wrong? and why work in postman but not on my site?

Comment: In your first example you want to get data, so set `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'` instead of `POST`

Comment: @wouch yea I did not catch that but yes still not working.  When I var_dump it returns false

Comment: You need to decode the JSON response you get. Try adding this to the end of your first example `$result = json_decode($response); var_dump($result);`

Comment: unfortunatly still NULL.  I changed it to GET and decoded it.  I don't understand because when I just put the endpoint in the browser I get the results.

Comment: I think it's some authentication thing...  I need some token or something if I wanna use it like this.  But I don't see anything about getting tokens for wordpress sites

Comment: Get this, I did the call in javascript and it worked..